# SQL - Identical ID's different values in field, display all in one row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need some help with a query, as I haven't had much luck on my own.  Tried pivoting, amongst other things. Basically I'm trying to return the rows below into 1 row, as they have the same ID's. Can someone please assist? Thanks you!   [image]

```
 select distinct rf.resort, rf.guest_name_id,na.address1,na.address2,na.address3,na.address4,na.city,na.state,na.zip_code,na.country.phone_number
from rep_reservation_fin_all rf left join
     name_address na
     on rf.guest_name_id na.name_id left join
     name_phone np
     on rf.guest_name_id = np.name_id
where (rf.guest_name_id ='3966078') and
      (na.primary_YN = 'Y') and
      (np.primary_YN = 'Y')
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: A few questions... Which version of SQL Server are you using? Can you confirm if it's just phone_number field that may contain different values?? In the example, do you need the 2nd phone_number as a separate field or would it be ok if it was concatenated onto the first rows phone_number field.

Comment: Thanks guys! I just figured this out.  Just used a self join here.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out with a self join.  This might help someone else in case they run across a poorly constructed table like this.

```
select distinct rf.resort,rf.guest_name_id,na.address1,na.address2,na.address3,na.address4,na.city,na.state,na.zip_code,na.country,np.phone_number,npp.phone_number from rep_reservation_fin_all rfleft join name_address na on rf.guest_name_id =na.name_id left join name_phone np on rf.guest_name_id = np.name_id left join NAME_PHONE npp on np.NAME_ID = npp.NAME_ID  and np.PHONE_NUMBER like '%@%'where (rf.guest_name_id ='3966078')and (na.primary_YN = 'Y') and (np.primary_YN = 'Y') and (npp.PHONE_NUMBER not like '%@%')
```